# MYSQL based queries in Oracle Database 12c

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle12c, where-clause

The below queries working fine in `MYSQL` Database.

```
select * from accounts where preferred_email like "%p.rajesh%";
select * from account_external_ids where external_id like "%p.rajesh%";
```

We have `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit` in that when i tried to run getting below error.

```
select * from accounts where preferred_email like '%p.rajesh%';
ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

select * from account_external_ids where external_id like '%p.rajesh%';
ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

It looks doesn't Oracle deal with semicolon. i am new to Oracle, Can you help me to run above MYSQL queries in Oracle?

Comment: How are you submitting the query? Oracle uses a semi-colon too, but some applications - especially some Java or JDBC libraries - add that for you automatically. If you add your own, it submits the query with two semi-colons and generates the error you see. If you're getting this error using sqlplus then something else is wrong.

Comment: i am using `gerrit gsql` through this i have connected our oracle database from that terminal i am running.

Comment: Try using sqlplus. It appears that gsql is designed primarily to work with H2, so there may be a compatibility issue.